# How to efficiently mitigate "cycle bias"

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am looping through the neighbors of a matrix element in order to find the smallest one as follows, while also saving its coordinates:

```
int minimum_r = curr_r; 
int minimum_c = curr_c;
uint8_t tmp_value = 255;

for (int i = curr_r - 1; i <= curr_r + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = curr_c - 1; j <= curr_c + 1; j++) {
        uint8_t value = src[i * cols + j];
        if (value < tmp_value) {
            tmp_value = value;
            minimum_r = i;
            minimum_c = j;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am noticing is that if there are more than one minimum neighbors with same `value`, the first one to be checked will be selected. I remember reading about this "cycle bias" problem somewhere, but I can't recall the correct term for it.

The snippet is from an algorithm to compute gradient descent, and I'm thinking that maybe I can mitigate the issue by finding the "sub-pixel" gradient. Am I missing a simpler solution here?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

EDIT:

To be clear, my main question is:
How is this programming issue referred to usually, if it is at all, so that I can look for it online (I remember reading about it before, and it was termed in a specific way).

Comment: Please add an example of a matrix showing a) what result you get and b) what result you expected. It looks to that it will select the first but maybe you mean something different when you write "last one"

Comment: "_the last one to be checked will be selected_" - Are you sure about that? It looks like the first one to me.

Comment: It doesn't look as if all neighbors are checked - did you mean to use `i <= curr_r + 1`

Comment: @Ted - You are right, the first one will be selected, thank you. The problem is still there.

Comment: @user445082 Which problem is still there?

Comment: it sounds like this question is better suited for our [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [computational science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) sites since the issue doesn't seem to be a problem of programming *per se*. You might get more direct answers like if the bias is ignoreable or mitigated by randomization or some other heuristic.

Comment: @4386427 - Yes, sorry, I simplified the code to post it and missed the "<="s

Comment: If it's bias you want to avoid can't you just select one of the equal points at random?

Comment: @user445082 Please edit the question to 1) correct the first/last problem and 2) explain what your problem is - currently it's unclear.

Comment: Is the current point supposed to be included in the neighbour check?

Comment: `uint8_t tmp_value = 255;` --> `uint8_t tmp_value = src[curr_r * cols + curr_c];` ?

Comment: @user445082 So the problem is that the algorithm **always** selects the first one - is that it? So what do you want instead? The last one? The one to the left? A random one? You need to clarify what it is you are looking for!

Comment: Your text says: "I am looping through the neighbors of a matrix element" but yout code is **also including tme element itself" - is that intended?

Comment: "_How is this programming issue referred to usually_" - I think _bias_ **is** the proper term.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of elements considered is sufficiently large enough and the selection does not need to be stable, randomizing the selected element is a local solution.

The easiest way would be to randomize the first element to look at (i.e. not to start in the same corner all the time).

If randomizing is not an option, use a "at which corner to start" counter, incremented for each check.

To implement either of these, move the offsets to a list:

```
int offs[][2] = { {-1,-1 }, { -1, 0 }, { -1, 1 }, .... };
```

You can now loop through that:

```
for(int neighbourIdx = 0; neighbourIdx < 8; ++neighbourIdx)
// look at neighbour [curr_r+offs[neighbourIdx][0], curr_c+offs[neighbourIdx][1]]
```

This is equivalent to your solution. To allow an arbitrary start, make `offs` twice as long, going through all neighbours twice, then start at an arbitrary offset

```
int startOffset = random(0,7); // or (++counter) % 8
for(int neighbourIdx = startOffset; neighbourIdx < startOffset+8; ++neighbourIdx)
// ... as above
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to efficiently mitigate “cycle bias”? ...The problem I am noticing is that if there are more than one minimum neighbors with same value, the first one to be checked will be selected.

As I mentioned in a comment, one way to avoid bias would be to select one of those neighbours at random.

To make it reasonably quick and accurate, I'd create a list of the neighbours - and to not favour any neighbours over others, I'd create a table of all the permutations in which order the neighbours can be searched. You then only need to randomly select a permutation to guarantee a bias free selection.

Idea:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

inline std::mt19937& generator() {
    static thread_local std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
    return gen;
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>* = nullptr>
T my_rand(T min, T max) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dist(min, max);
    return dist(generator());
}

auto make_permutations() {
    std::vector<std::array<std::pair<int8_t, int8_t>, 8>> result;
    result.reserve(40320); // * 2 == 80640 bytes

    // it's important that this entered as the first permutation (sorted)
    std::array<std::pair<int8_t, int8_t>, 8> ne{
        {{-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}};

    do { // loop over all the permutations and store them
        result.push_back(ne);
    } while(std::next_permutation(ne.begin(), ne.end()));

    return result;
}

using rc = std::pair<size_t, size_t>; // row column alias

rc get_lowest_neighbour(size_t curr_r, size_t curr_c,
                        const uint8_t (&src)[rows * cols]) {
    static const auto nperm = make_permutations();

    // select a random permutation
    const auto& neighbours = nperm[my_rand(0ul, nperm.size() - 1)];

    // initialize low-score with the first neighbour in the permutation
    auto it = neighbours.begin();

    size_t r = curr_r + it->first;
    size_t c = curr_c + it->second;
    uint8_t tmp_value = src[r * cols + c];
    rc result = {r, c};

    // search the rest of the neighbours for a lower score
    for(++it; it != neighbours.end(); ++it) {
        r = curr_r + it->first;
        c = curr_c + it->second;
        uint8_t value = src[r * cols + c];
        if(value < tmp_value) {
            tmp_value = value;
            result = {r, c};
        }
    }

    return result;
}

//...
auto [row, col] = get_lowest_neighbour(y, x, src);
```